# JS: Lint error: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, standardjs

I do get an standardJs lint error

```
/lib/with-apollo-client.js:7:24: Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

for this snippet, which is from https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-apollo/lib/with-apollo-client.js

```
import initApollo from './init-apollo'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { getDataFromTree } from 'react-apollo'

export default (App) => {
  return class Apollo extends React.Component {
    static displayName = 'withApollo(App)' // <-
    static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    // ...
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong with that? I'm using standardJs 11.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you cannot define class properties in this way without a transform:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Instance_properties